# RuntimeError: Indicator "RSIIndica…(C,14)" errored with exception: '_Array' object has no attribute 'diff'

Tags: python

I'm trying to backtest strategies using Backtesting.py. When I run this code I get the error

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ta
from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy
from backtesting.lib import crossover
from ta.volatility import BollingerBands
from ta.momentum import RSIIndicator
from backtesting.test import GOOG

# get Ethereum data from Yahoo Finance
eth = yf.download("ETH-USD", start ="2018-01-01")




class RsiOscillator(Strategy):

    upper_bound = 70
    lower_bound = 30

    def init(self):
        self.rsi = self.I(ta.momentum.RSIIndicator,self.data.Close,14)

    def next(self):
        
        if crossover(self.rsi, self.upper_bound):
            self.position.close()

        elif crossover(self.lower_bound, self.rsi):
            self.buy()

bt = Backtest(GOOG,RsiOscillator,cash=10000,commission=0.002)
stats = bt.run()
print(stats)
```

```
RuntimeError: Indicator "RSIIndica…(C,14)" errored with exception: '_Array' object has no attribute 'diff'
```

I saw this code in a video and it runs perfectly so I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Try `self.data.Close.values` in the `__init__` function

Comment: I had the same issue and i solved it by ussing the metthod ta.momentum.rsi  insted of ta.momentum.RSIIndicator .

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the type of `self.data.Close`, like this:
`pd.Series(self.data.Close)`

And you may face the `AttributeError`.
try this:

```
self.upper_bound = 70
self.lower_bound = 30
```